# How to configure linphone-web-ui on windows based environment?

Tags: voip, linphone

I am working on VOIP using Linphone-web-ui but i have some difficulties while configuring it on my local machine. i have download a clone from git and trying to install using GRUNT and NPM Shell commands,i have installed the dependent libraries mentioned in the package.json file but An error occurred when i run the command "grunt develop" the error is in a library named "grunt-oversprite" and error is "Fatal Error!Unsupported interlace method".

please help me out of this problem.